# When to use KeyboardEvent vs addEventListener for keyup

Tags: javascript, events, closures

I've seen examples where to add an event listener, both a KeyboardEvent is created/dispatched and an addEventListener is called.  Is there a reason to do both (maybe older IE versions)?  Or is simply `addEventListener` enough to support all browsers + >= IE11.

```
const keyboard = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true });

document.addEventListener('keyup', _closureMethod, false);

document.dispatchEvent(keyboard);
```

Comment: Where have you seen this? this feels like a hack to me. What he's trying to do with `dispatch(new KeyboardEvent(...))` is simulate a keypress, or more precise the *keyup* part of a keypress. I'm not sure, why he doesn't simply call the handler, like `_closureMethod();`. This has nothing to do with simply adding an eventListener and browser compatibility; he's trying something else here.

Comment: I have only used addEventListener for as long as I can remember. Seems to be enough. Old browsers are subjective. Anything older than IE9, in my opinion should be regarded as ancient text books. So I would not care if there's no support for anything older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing two different things:

- when using `addEventListener` on `keyup`, you wait for a `keyup` event to be triggered by the press of a keyboard button.
- creating a `KeyboardEvent` and dispatching it *simulates* a `keyup` event. You don't need an event listener for that, because it's an *artificial* event.